# Limit SiteTree based on current member in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible to limit the view of the site tree to one particular node based on the logged in user?

When an administrator is logged in they will have access to all root nodes:

- Melbourne

  - Melbourne page one
  - Melbourne page two
- Sydney

  - Sydney page one
  - Sydney page two

When someone that belongs to the Melbourne group is logged in all they will be able to see is:

- Melbourne page one
- Melbourne page two

Comment: Can you use the fine tuned permission level settings on pages (parents in this case) for this? E.g. "who can view" and "who can edit" this page?

Comment: That seems to only limit the viewing (front end) and editing of that page but those pages will still be visible in the SiteTree to that user.

Comment: I see. There may be an extension hook to filter the site tree in admin. Will check tomorrow

Comment: Yeah I had a quick look for one and couldn't see any, I may have been looking in the wrong class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new extension with this functions:

- `canView($member = null)`

  Defines if the page should be visible in the CMS for current user.
- `canEdit($member = null)`

  Defines if current user can edit the page.
- `canCreate($member = null)`

  Defines if current user can create new page.
- `canDelete($member = null)`

  Defines if current user can delete the page.
- `canPublish($member = null)`

  Defines if current user can publish draft page.

All hooks can return 3 values:

1. TRUE - grant access
2. FALSE - deny access
3. NULL - no decision, continue with next extension. All DataObjects finish the decision loop with fall back to ADMIN permission.

So you can create your own permission logic.

```
class CMSTreeChildrenFilter extends Extension
{

    public function augmentAllChildrenIncludingDeleted($children, $context) {

        if (!is_a($context, 'CMSPagesController')) return;

        foreach ($children as $page) {
            if (!$page->canView()) {
                $children->remove($page);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However in your case the following configuration should work:

1. Configure root pages (Melbourne and Sydney) to have 'Only these people' can view and edit the page and select corresponding group.
2. All pages in the branch should inherit the permission from parent page.
3. Other root pages that inherit permission from the 'root' are configured in SiteConfig. Navigate to Settings / Access and select Administrators group to be able to view and edit the pages.

By default root pages are disabled but still visible in the site tree when user has no access to them. You can hide them with this extra css style:

```
.cms-tree .disabled {display:none;}
```

Comment: Have you tested to confirm that this actually removes them from the tree in admin?

Comment: By default all root pages are displayed, but for those that user has no access are disabled. You can apply custom css style to hide them.

Comment: That is exactly what I am after. For bonus points, do you know how to add a custom class to the site tree node? I am attempting to add a new one using the 'CMSTreeClasses' method http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-SiteTree.html#2732-2768. It appears to do absolutely nothing on my extension class.

Comment: you should define this method directly on SiteTree derived class (CustomPage::CMSTreeClasses), check VirtualPage for example.